# Webstart WinNTFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes-Performance

Tags: io, java-web-start

I am distributing an application via jnlp (without sandbox, all-permissions-flag set) which works fine.
But all calls to the file-system (especially File.exists()) take forever.
Via profiler I was able to narrow down the problem to WinNTFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes, which is invoked in the File.exists()-method.

If I start the application directly (without jnlp/webstart), everything works fine.

On a mac-machine, the application is fast even if started through webstart.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling your anti-virus and firewalls to see if they cause the long delay.